# Why do I get "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" when I override console.log?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code..

```
function getMilli(){
    return new Date().getTime().toString().substr(7,6);
}
console.log = function(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6){
    console.log(getMilli(), p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
}
```

It somehow does a "stack overflow" error but I don't get it why here.. I'm not recursively iterating things (at least I think)

---

...uh, yeah I was doing recursive stuff... but I didn't know how to do it. Thanks for the answers and great concepts.

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion too me !
You're calling console.log from console.log ever and ever.

Comment: because you are calling console.log from within console.log?

Comment: What you have here is log-ception... A log in a log in a log in a log...

Comment: Avoid using p1, p2, p3 etc. if you can.

Comment: @AtesGoral: thanks, yeah I just did it for quick demo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an improvement to other answers that work:

1. Avoid polluting the global scope or the properties of any object to store the original console.log.
2. Avoid having to specify an arbitrary number of placeholder arguments like p1, p2, p3, etc.

Use a closure to store the original `console.log` and also remove the dependency on arbitrary argument declarations:

```
console.log = function (log) {
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.unshift(getMillis()); // Push millis as first argument
        log.apply(console, args);
    };
}(console.log);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9BPuc/

Comment: there's definitely a lot of stuff going on here, but this is the best way of implementing this! thanks :)

Comment: just a question: is the reason you called var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); is because you're converting the non-array-type arguments into an array so you can use "unshift" method for arrays? (i'm new to JavaScript)

Comment: @JanCarloViray That's correct. This is a common pattern for converting `arguments` into a regular Array.

Comment: I'm wondering why not just use it without [call]? Is it because it would overwrite Array.prototype.slice? So by using call, you prevent it from being overwritten?

Comment: @JanCarloViray `slice` is not a static utility method but an instance method (i.e. you need an Array instance to begin with). However, it also works on any array-like object. Here, we're simulating `arguments.slice()` by calling `Array.prototype.slice` with `arguments` as the scope object. `slice`, when called without arguments, is akin to calling it with `slice(0)`, so it basically makes a copy of the array. We're making a copy of `arguments` as a regular Array.

Answer (score 4):

You *are* recursively calling the function `console.log`. In other words, you're calling `console.log` within `console.log`.

What you probably meant to do is:

```
(function(){

    var clog = console.log.bind(console);

    console.log = function(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6){
        clog(getMilli(), p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
    }

})();
```

Comment: ASDF beat me by 28 seconds. Will delete my answer and edit yours to include the `bind` trick, which I've found to be necessary in most browsers.

Comment: While I understand that this is just to demonstrate a quick way, it would be nicer if you didn't pollute the global namespace with a variable called `clog`.

Answer (score 1):

apparently you are calling `console.log` from within `console.log` because when you reassign it to new function it does not retain link to the old one(and why should it?)

what you want to do instead is this:

```
console.old_log = console.log;

console.log = function() { 
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.unshift(getMilli()); 
  console.old_log.apply(console, args)
}
```

Comment: thanks for contributing, although check out the 'Answer' for a better implementation by @AtesGoral